# ggplot scale gradient color in R

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot and am having issues with the scale_colour_gradient2() function. Whenever I include the argument in the following code, I get an error.

```
cor_mat <- matrix(sample(rnorm(100), 49), ncol = 7, nrow = 7)
rownames(cor_mat) <- c("H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7")
colnames(cor_mat) <- c("H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7")
cor_mat_melt <- melt(cor_mat)           

ggplot(cor_mat_melt, aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + labs(x = "", y = "") +     scale_colour_gradient2(low = "red", high = "blue")
```

Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `scale_color_gradient` when there's no color to scale. You'll want to use `scale_fill_gradient` or change `fill=value` to `color=value`